# What happens if we reassign database/sql rows object to a result of new Query()? Does it close it automatically? Or should we close it ourselves?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm working with postgresql using Golang, and I'm in a situation where I have to do several queries. If I store the results of each query in the same variable let's call it "rows", reassigning that variable each time to a new result of query, will it automatically close previous rows? Or should I each time close them manually? And if I should close them manually what happens if I defer rows.Close() each time? Is that so necessary?

Answer (score 0):

How about calling `Rows.Close()` *before`you assign to`rows` again?

And no, `Rows.Close()` is not automatically called by a reassignment. If you do several *different* queries, use *different* variables to hold the rows returned by each. Call `defer rows.Close()` for each after assigning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `rows.Close()` before each reassignment. By this way you will free memory from contents of "rows" pointer.
Also, be careful with `defer rows.Close()`, because:

1. You'll free rows only at function end, not immediately. Just keep this in mind.
2. If `rows` is not a pointer - it will call `Close()` only for last assigned object.